# jQuery simple value get issue with .val()

Tags: jquery, get

I have the following code:

```
$('.document').ready(function(){
   alert($('font.someClass').val());
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wwzD/1/) with it.

Does anyone know why I can not return the value of a font tag?

Am I to assume that you are not allowed to call the value or set the value of a font tag.

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I'm a developer not a designer, I wasn't sure if this was something that was coming back into style or what haha - do whatcha gotta do I suppose :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.text()` not `.val()` - `.val()` is for form elements.

Answer (score 3):

The `val()` method get values from `value` which exists for form elements (like `input`).
You is looking to get the text from some DOM element, so use the `text()` method.

I updated your Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2wwzD/2/) with the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($("font.someClass").text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the text:

```
$('.document').ready(function(){
 alert($('font.someClass').text());
});
```